# Randomly written numbers in a game made in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game and I would like every time I open the game, the numbers to be random, but it doesn't work with my code.
Here is my code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(600, 400);
       frame.setVisible(true);           
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel center = new JPanel();
       center.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 1, 1));

       int z = 0;               
Random random = new Random();
       for(int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
       int size = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
       }

       frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The `size` variable is local to the `for` loop and you don't do anything with it. What do you need it to do?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You are looping `for k from 0 to z`, where z=0. You shall set `z` to number of iterations (how many times you want the loop execute). In the loop you set the `size` variable, but you don't do anything with it. If you want to print it, then print it `System.out.println(size);`

Comment: my first code was like this: 
JPanel center = new JPanel();
     center.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 1, 1));
     int z = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
       
       JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(++z));
       center.add(button);
      }
     }
So, I wanted to look just like this but the numbers to be different every time I open the game and not static from 1-36 like with this code. But when I delete this code and use java.util.Random, also I can't make the field where i want the numbers to be written.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop is doing 0 iterations, that means whatever is inside it never runs :

```
for(int k = 0; k < z; k++) { ...
```

You need to have int z set to something bigger than 0 if you want to have the code inside the for loop run at leasdt once..

Comment: my first code was like this: JPanel center = new JPanel(); center.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 1, 1)); int z = 0; for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(++z)); center.add(button); } } So, I wanted to look just like this but the numbers to be different every time I open the game and not static from 1-36 like with this code. But when I delete this code and use java.util.Random, also I can't make the field where i want the numbers to be written.